# Splash screen at the beginning of app

Tags: android

I need some help. I have a problem with my app. I want to put a splash screen at the beginning. I have done it before. I have made the code, the layout, and all works perfectly in a new project! When I put the code I run it on my phone and the layout in my application, the application runs perfectly without any errors. But when I open it on my phone, it stops and it doesn't open it!!! Can you suggest something??

my android manifest.xml:

```
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Show your error log inf o.

Comment: I don't have any errors at android studio my problem is at my phone the app runs fine when my application goes to open in my phone it crashes it doesn't open!! And I tried fixing my splash screen in a new project ant running it on my phone at it works perfect it doesn't crash !!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to launch Main activity from your SplashScreenActivity.

In your SplashScreenActivity's onCreate():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The first 2 lines launch Main activity through an Intent, and the 3rd line kills SplashScreenActivity so you cannot go back to it from MainActivity.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

Comment: this is my code  LoginActivity is the next layout that I want to open after my splash screen

Comment: SplashScreenActivity.this.finish(); is redundant.

Comment: Just use finish(); unless you're in an inner class.

Comment: It would be much easier if we saw your SplashScreenActivity code.

Comment: No. You NEVER EVER put a timer to stop your app from loading. You put that Intent in onCreate(). The purpose of a splash screen is just to show your user something while your app loads and ONLY WHEN your app is loading.

Comment: I want to show my user a logo of a company for 3 or 5 or 6  second before he gets into the app!!what do u recommend ?

Comment: Forcing a user to stay longer on a splash screen leads to bad UX. It's overall bad design because what if a user has a lower end device? In addition to the load time, they are forced to wait an additional 3 seconds on top of that. The user will eventually stop using your app from impatience. Just forget about the idea of making your splash screen lasting more than 3 seconds and give your users a good experience.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!! and what other ways have I got to advertise for a bit a logo at the begging?? I made the  splash screen for 2 or 3 sec just to show something to my user that he has to see!! but my problem is that it crashes when its installed at my phone with my application but when i put my code that i send u in a new project without my app only the splash screen (java and layout) and pressed run it didn't crashed ant showed me perfect the result!! that's my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  int SLEEP_TIMER = 3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade);

    imageView.startAnimation(animation);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    LogoLauncher logoLauncher = new LogoLauncher();
    logoLauncher.start();


}

private class LogoLauncher extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000  * SLEEP_TIMER);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```